# Notion APIs with Google Calendar

Tags: python, api, google-calendar-api, notion-api

If I search on the web something like " Notion API with Google Calendar", I only find solution related to Automate.io or Zappier.

Is there a way to use these powerful APIs to integrate Notion with Google Calendar, **without** rely on those sites?
Which programming language can I use to do that? Do I need a server to run the program periodically?

PS: On YT I found something with Python, but I cannot find a complete guide to use these tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Which programming language can I use to do that?**

You can easily use [Google App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and [Notion API](https://developers.notion.com) to achieve this. The syntax of Google app script is based on javascript (although some ES6 features are not supported). With the [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app), you can practically control all the content on your Google Calendar.

**Do I need a server to run the program periodically?**

No you don't need to. In Google App Script, you can add [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to let it start automatically.

[image]

#### Here's a simple example to sync notion to calendar:

##### Use UrlFetchApp to post query to your Notion database

In this case, I will set the date of the event, according to 'DeadLine' property. So I attached a filter to exclude empty values.

[image]

```
function main() {
    let data = {
        "filter": {
            "property": "DeadLine",
            "date": {
                "is_not_empty": true
            }
        }
    };

    let options = {
        'method': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'headers': {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'your integration token',
            'Notion-Version': '2021-05-13',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/your_database_id/query', options);
    response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    //other code
}
```

##### Create a new calendar event

The `page` is one of the `response.results` array. Here we use `page.id` and `database_id` as the unique identifier of the event. And need to distinguish whether the deadline contains time or only date.

There are two variables to deal with here:

- have end date or not
- have time or only date

```
const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("your calendar id");
const onlyDateRegex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\b/;
const dateTimeRegex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\.(\d{3})\+(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\b/;

function create(page) {
    let deadLine = page.properties.DeadLine;
    let title = "";
    page.properties.Name.title.forEach((rich_text) => {
        title += rich_text.plain_text;
    })
    let pageId = page.id + " in database " + page.parent.database_id;

    let startDate = deadLine.date.start;
    let endDate = deadLine.date.end;
    let startDateObj = new Date(startDate);
    let endDateObj = new Date(endDate);

    let evnet;
    Logger.log("Create page " + title);

    if (deadLine.date.end !== null) {
        if (onlyDateRegex.test(startDate))
            evnet = calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, startDateObj, endDateObj);

        if (dateTimeRegex.test(startDate))
            evnet = calendar.createEvent(title, startDateObj, endDateObj);

    } else {
        if (onlyDateRegex.test(startDate))
            evnet = calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, startDateObj);

        if (dateTimeRegex.test(startDate))
            evnet = calendar.createEvent(title, startDateObj, startDateObj);
    }
    evnet.setDescription(pageId);
}
```

##### Then we can use the id in the description to search for pages that have been synchronized

Here continues the main function in the first step.

```
function main() {

    //other code

    response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    for (let i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
        let pageId = response.results[i].id + " in database " + response.results[i].parent.database_id;
        let event = search(pageId);
        if (event === null) create(response.results[i]);
        else update(event, response.results[i]);
    }
}

function search(str) {
    let events = calendar.getEvents(new Date("1970-1-1"), new Date("2100-1-1"), {
        search: str
    });
    if (events.length > 1) throw new Error("uuid duplicate in search");
    if (events.length === 0) return null;
    return events[0];
}
```

If no result is found, create a new event, otherwise, try to update it.

##### The practice of updating an event is almost the same as when it was created

```
function update(event, page) {

    let deadLine = page.properties.DeadLine;
    let title = "";
    page.properties.Name.title.forEach((rich_text) => {
        title += rich_text.plain_text;
    })

    Logger.log("Update page " + title);

    let startDate = deadLine.date.start;
    let endDate = deadLine.date.end;
    let startDateObj = new Date(startDate);
    let endDateObj = new Date(endDate);

    if (deadLine.date.end !== null) {
        if (onlyDateRegex.test(startDate)) {
            startDateObj.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            endDateObj.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if (event.isAllDayEvent()) {
                if ((event.getAllDayStartDate().getTime() !== startDateObj.getTime()) ||
                    (event.getAllDayEndDate().getTime() !== endDateObj.getTime())) {
                    Logger.log("update allDayStartDate " + event.getAllDayStartDate() + " to " + startDateObj);
                    Logger.log("update allDayEndDate " + event.getAllDayEndDate() + " to " + endDateObj);
                    event.setAllDayDates(startDateObj, endDateObj);
                }
            } else event.setAllDayDates(startDateObj, endDateObj);
        }
        if (dateTimeRegex.test(startDate)) {
            if (event.isAllDayEvent()) {
                Logger.log("change to dateTime, start: " + startDateObj + " end: " + endDateObj);
                event.setTime(startDateObj, endDateObj);
            } else {
                if ((event.getStartTime().getTime() !== startDateObj.getTime()) ||
                    (event.getEndTime().getTime() !== endDateObj.getTime())) {
                    Logger.log("update dateTime, start: " + startDateObj + " end: " + endDateObj);
                    event.setTime(startDateObj, endDateObj);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (onlyDateRegex.test(startDate)) {
            startDateObj.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if (event.isAllDayEvent()) {
                if ((event.getAllDayStartDate().getTime() !== startDateObj.getTime()) ||
                    (event.getAllDayEndDate().getTime() !== startDateObj.getTime())) {
                    Logger.log("update allOneDayDate " + event.getAllDayStartDate() + " to " + startDateObj);
                    event.setAllDayDate(startDateObj);
                }
            } else {
                Logger.log("change to allOneDayDate: " + startDateObj);
                event.setAllDayDates(startDateObj);
            }
        }
        if (dateTimeRegex.test(startDate)) {
            if (event.isAllDayEvent()) {
                Logger.log("change to dateTime: " + startDateObj);
                event.setTime(startDateObj, startDateObj);
            } else {
                if (event.getStartTime().getTime() !== startDateObj.getTime()) {
                    Logger.log("update dateTime: " + startDateObj);
                    event.setTime(startDateObj, startDateObj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (event.getTitle() !== title) {
        Logger.log("update title: \"" + event.getTitle() + "\" to " + title);
        event.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

[Full example code](https://gist.github.com/YukinaMochizuki/830ad7fed4cc68d5a408bd1ea4307bee)

I am not a professional javascript or Google App Script engineer, these codes may still need improvement, hope this is useful.